# Adding elements to a XAML Canvas C#

Tags: c#, xaml, canvas

I have a windows 8 app created in xml and using code-behind.
I have a button that, when pressed, will create a canvas, and put a grid inside of it.

```
    private void AddClass_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        SolidColorBrush greenBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Green);
        Thickness size = new Thickness();

        size.Top = 20;
        size.Right = 20;
        size.Left = 20;
        size.Bottom = 20;
        Canvas newcanvas = new Canvas();
        newcanvas.Background = greenBrush;
        newcanvas.Width=500; 
        newcanvas.Height=500; 
        newcanvas.Margin=size;
        newcanvas.Name = "Class3";
        GridView temp = new GridView();
        newcanvas.Children.Add(temp);
        classes.Items.Add(newcanvas);

    }
```

What I need to now be able to do is, add MORE elements into the canvas I've just created, at any given time using a button, but I'm not sure how to reference this newly created canvas.

Comment: Are you saying you'll be adding multiple canvases?  Each time the user touches the button you want another canvas?

Comment: If there are multiple canvases, how do you know which one the user intends as the target for the additional items?

Answer (score 1):

Save a ref at the class level:

```
Canvas myCanvas;
```

then create it only the first time:

```
private void AddClass_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(myCanvas == null)
    {
        myCanvas = new Canvas();
        newcanvas.Background = greenBrush;
        newcanvas.Width=500; 
        newcanvas.Height=500; 
        newcanvas.Margin=size;
        newcanvas.Name = "Class3";
    }
    GridView temp = new GridView();
    newcanvas.Children.Add(temp);
    classes.Items.Add(newcanvas);
}
```

But why not define you `Canvas` in XAML? Then if you give it a name you can refer to in code-behind:

```
<Canvas Name="myCanvas" Width="500" ...>
</Canvas>

private void AddClass_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myCanvas.Children.Add(new GridView());
}
```

Comment: I should have been more clear, I need to add elements to the canvases individually

Comment: That seems like a different question, you said: "add MORE elements into the canvas I've just created". If you want to create a new canvas every click stash in a list - which you seem to have started doing..

Comment: The reason I don't define it in xaml is because I cannot tell how many canavases will be needed. I could need up to thousands.

Comment: would a dictionary be better to use than a list?

Comment: it all depends on what you need to do, if you don't need to access them you don't event need to stash them

Comment: what you are doing is quite unconventional though, I suspect you shouldn't be doing what you are doing, do you perhaps need a list of things - why not use a ListView or ListBox?

Comment: I need to create a UI with interactable groups of people, and I need to be able to add groups and people, and be able to remove them too, all while having them both be interactable via button, tap, etc. Also, all of these people will have their own profile.

Answer (score 0):

Simply move your Canvas declaration

```
Canvas newcanvas = new Canvas();
```

outside the function but within the scope you plan to address it from.

Later when you want to reference it again from the code behind on your button, it will still exist.

Comment: I should have been more clear, I need to add elements to the canvases individually

Answer (score 0):

Since you added newly created canvas this way :

```
classes.Items.Add(newcanvas);
```

Then I think, first thing to try to access it later is from `Items` property of `classes` :

```
classes.Items
```

If you have more then one object in `Items`, just iterate through `Items` and check if the item type is `Canvas`.